# Datetime difference casting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

DateTime1: `2010-11-23 15:30:00.000`

DateTime2: `2010-11-23 18:30:00.000`

DateTime2 - DateTime1 should be `03:00:00`

but when I use below query

```
SELECT (EndTime - StartTime) as Hour From [Day]
```

it returns

```
1900-01-01 03:00:00.000
```

how can I get it like `03:00`?

Comment: What would you want `20120717 12:00:00 - 20120716 09:00:00` to show as? `03:00` or `27:00` or `1d 03:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datediff function is suitable for this operation.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF ( hour , StartTime, EndTime ) as hour From [Day]
```

and have a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, `DATEDIFF` is suitable. Formatting is probably best left to the client side, however the below will work as you have requested

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = '20120716 09:00',
        @End DATETIME = '20120717 12:00'

SELECT  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, @Start, @End) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + CAST(DATEDIFF(HOUR, @Start, @End) AS VARCHAR) + ':' + 
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Start, @End) - (DATEDIFF(HOUR, @Start, @End) * 60) AS VARCHAR), 2) [Difference]
```